# Perl DBI and sql now()

Tags: perl, dbi

I have been trying to use sql NOW() function while I update a table. But nothing happens to that date field, I think DBI just ignores that value. Code is :

```
dbUpdate($id, (notes => 'This was an update', filesize => '100.505', dateEnd => 'NOW()'));
```

and the function is :

```
sub dbUpdate {
    my $id = shift;
    my %val_hash = @_;
    my $table = 'backupjobs';

    my @fields = keys %val_hash;
    my @values = values %val_hash;

    my $update_stmt = "UPDATE $table SET ";
    my $count = 1;
    foreach ( @fields ) {
        $update_stmt .=  "$_ = ? ";
        $update_stmt .=  ', ' if ($count != scalar @fields);
        $count++;
    }
    $update_stmt .= " WHERE ID = ?";
    print "update_stmt is : $update_stmt\n";
    my $dbo = dbConnect();
    my $sth = $dbo->prepare( $update_stmt );
    $sth->execute( @values, $id ) or die "DB Update failed : $!\n";
    $dbo->disconnect || die "Failed to disconnect\n";
    return 1;
}#dbUpdate
```

As you can see this is a "dynamic" generation of the sql query and hence I dont know where an sql date function(like now()) come.

In the given example the sql query will be

```
UPDATE backupjobs SET filesize = ? , notes = ? , dateEnd = ?  WHERE ID = ?
```

with param values

```
100.55, This was an update, NOW(), 7
```

But the date column still shows 0000-00-........

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have been trying to use sql NOW() function while I update a table. But
>   nothing happens to that date field, I think DBI just ignores that
>   value.

No, it doesn't. But the DB thinks you are supplying a datetime or timestamp data type when you are in fact trying to add the string `NOW()`. That of course doesn't work. Unfortunately DBI cannot find that out for you. All it does is change `?` into an escaped (via `$dbh->quote()`) version of the string it got.

There are several things you could do:

1. Supply a current timestamp string in the appropriate format instead of the string `NOW()`.

   If you have it available, you can use [`DateTime::Format::MySQL`](http://p3rl.org/DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aMySQL) like this:

   ```
   use DateTime::Format::MySQL;
   dbUpdate(
     $id,
     (
       notes => 'This was an update',
       filesize => '100.505',
       dateEnd => DateTime::Format::MySQL->format_datetime(DateTime->now),
     )
   );
   ```

   If not, just use [`DateTime`](http://p3rl.org/DateTime) or [`Time::Piece`](http://p3rl.org/Time%3a%3aPiece).

   ```
       use DateTime;
       my $now = DateTime->now->datetime;
       $now =~ y/T/ /;
       dbUpdate(
         $id,
         (notes => 'This was an update', filesize => '100.505', dateEnd => $now));
   ```
2. Tell your `dbUpdate` function to look for things like `NOW()` and react accordingly.

   You can do something like this. But there are better ways to code this. You should also consider that there is e.g. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` as well.

   ```
   sub dbUpdate {
       my $id = shift;
       my %val_hash = @_;
       my $table = 'backupjobs';

       my $update_stmt = "UPDATE $table SET ";

       # Check for the NOW() value
       # This could be done with others too
       foreach ( keys %val_hash ) {
         if ($val_hash{$_} =~ m/^NOW\(\)$/i) {
           $update_stmt .= "$_ = NOW()";
           $update_stmt .= ', ' if scalar keys %val_hash > 1;
           delete $val_hash{$_};
         }
       }

       # Put everything together, join keeps track of the trailing comma
       $update_stmt .= join(', ', map { "$_=?" } keys %val_hash );
       $update_stmt .= " WHERE ID = ?";
       say "update_stmt is : $update_stmt";
       say "values are: ", join(', ', values %val_hash);

       my $dbo = dbConnect();
       my $sth = $dbo->prepare( $update_stmt );
       $sth->execute( values %val_hash, $id ) or die "DB Update failed : $!\n";
       $dbo->disconnect || die "Failed to disconnect\n";
       return 1;
   }
   ```
3. Write your queries yourself.

   You're probably not going to do it and I'll not add an example since you know how to do it anyway.

---

Here's something else: Is this the only thing you do with your database while your program runs? It is not wise to connect and disconnect the database every time you make a query. It would be better for performance to connect the database once you need it (or at the beginning of the program, if you always use it) and just use this dbh/dbo everywhere. It saves a lot of time (and code).

Comment: If anyone knows how to format the bold stuff into a list and preserve the code, please go ahead. I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but you can't use `NOW()` as an interpolated value like that.

when a `?` is used in an SQL statement, the corresponding value is (via some mechanism or other) passed to the database escaped, so whatever value is interpreted as a string, not as SQL.  So you are in effect attempting to use the string `'NOW()'` as a date value, not the function `NOW()`.

To use `NOW()` as a function, you will have to insert it into the SQL itself rather than pass it as a bound value.  This means you will either have to use a hack of your `dbupdate` function or write a new one, or obtain the time as a string in perl and pass the resulting string the `dbupdate`.